# Get kernel version on Debian and Arch by offline

Tags: kernel, info

How can we know kernel version on Debian and Arch offline ?

i.e from other running Linux installed on another partition

Comment: mount the partition of other linux and use uname(command: uname -r) binary from that installation?

Comment: @FrontENG `uname` tells you about the running kernel, not another kernel stored elsewhere.

Comment: @FrontENG `uname` uses the running kernel; I have an installation with three different kernel versions, but just one `uname` binary...

Answer (score 4):

If you can determine which kernel binary (`/boot/vmlinuz...` on x86) would be used to boot a given system, `file` will tell you what kernel version it corresponds to:

```
$ file /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64
/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64: Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-vm-09.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) #1 SMP Tue Sep 7 07, RO-rootFS, swap_dev 0x9, Normal VGA
$ file /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-9-amd64
/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-9-amd64: Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 5.10.0-9-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) #1 SMP Debian 5.10.70-1 (2021-09-30), RO-rootFS, swap_dev 0x6, Normal VGA
```

To access the relevant files, mount the file system containing them (root or `/boot` etc.).

Comment: You'd also have to look at which default kernel would be started by the bootloader.
In general that would be the newest, but nor necessarily.

Comment: @Christo yes, which is why I wrote “if you can determine ...”.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it's impossible, it's not a question that has an answer - if the machine isn't running, there is no current kernel version.

The best you can do is examine the logs and configuration to try to find which kernel **was** running the last time the machine was up.  Which is good enough, and probably what you actually meant anyway.

Some likely things to check:

- Mount the appropriate partition from the machine and look at `/var/log/{kern,messages,syslog}*`, and maybe others.
- Some machines log `dmesg` output immediately after boot in `/var/log/dmesg` or similar.
- `journalctl`'s `--file` and/or `--root` options may allow you to access the machine's systemd journal.
- examine the machine's `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.
- The `saved_entry` line (if it's there) in `/boot/grub/grubenv` (if it exists) will tell you what the default grub menu option will be on the next boot....which may be the kernel that booted last (or maybe not, if a new kernel was installed and grub was updated since the last boot)

In all cases, I'd advise mounting partitions **read-only** unless you actually need to write any changes to them.

Answer (score 0):

Mount the partition with the `/boot` directory of the "offline" Linux into the "online" Linux, look at the contents.

At least on Debian, the `vmlinuz` file(s) inside have the kernel version as part of the file name. You can even look at the kernel configuration for that particular kernel using the `config` files.

Comment: On Debian, looking at the file name doesn’t tell you everything, it only reflects the kernel ABI and not the actual kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct answer to that, like others mention there is no kernel running. Best way to pinpoint last running kernel is to parse for "***Linux version***" or "***BOOT_IMAGE=***" or "***Command line:***" in `/var/log/syslog` or use `journalctl`.

Other approach is to show all installed kernels via `ls /lib/modules` and assume the newest version was used.

Sometimes `ls -l /usr/src/linux` can be a good indicator too.